# Input text on any application with autohotkey gui

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to find a solution to add predefined text to any application so instead of remembering a hotkey/hotstring combination I'll just need to click on the GUI button for the text.

This is what I have right now:

```
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y20 w120 h40 , Title
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y70 w120 h40 , Paragraph
; Generated using SmartGUI Creator 4.0
Gui, Show, x152 y89 h131 w222, New GUI Window
Return

ButtonTitle:
Send Title
return

ButtonParagraph:
Send Paragraph 
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

My problem is that I'm not able to make it work properly. I just want to click the button and that word gets shot to the notepad/word/any application.

Comment: When you click on your GUI buttons - guess which is your active window (the one, the text will be sent to) then?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to always keep track of the current and the last active window. To achieve that you could use a shell hook to get notified when the active window changes: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/66726-method-to-detect-active-window-change/

So you could have two variables `currentWin` and `lastWin` and when the active window changes you set `lastWin := currentWin` and `currentWin := activeWin`.

Soemthing like this maybe:

```
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y20 w120 h40 , Title
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y70 w120 h40 , Paragraph
; Generated using SmartGUI Creator 4.0
Gui, Show, x152 y89 h131 w222, New GUI Window

Gui +LastFound 
hWnd := WinExist()
DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,Hwnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage(wParam, lParam) {
    If (wParam=4) { ;HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED
        lastWin := currentWin
        currentWin := "ahk_id " . lParam
    }
}

ButtonTitle:
WinActivate, % lastWin
Send Title
return

ButtonParagraph:
WinActivate, % lastWin
Send Paragraph 
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

(completely untested)

Comment: probably overkill (although looks like a clean solution) (also untested: {ALT}-{TAB} *should* switch to the last active window)

Comment: Good point! And since Alt+Tab can figure it out, there might even be a WinAPI function that returns the last active window.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Stephan and Forivin,

Thank you for your help. I used the alt+tab approach to solve the problem though I need to ensure that I get notepad on alt+tab keystroke or else it goes to another application. The below solves the problem.

Gui, Add, Button, x22 y20 w120 h40 , Title 
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y70 w120 h40 , Paragraph
Gui, Show, x152 y89 h131 w222, New GUI Window
Return

ButtonTitle:
Send, !{Esc}
Send Title
return

ButtonParagraph:
Send, !{Esc}
Send Paragraph
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp